# Android JNI native crash during garbage collection SIG 9 when using Pdfium Library

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to get access to pdf files in my app using https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid 
and adding some functions like searching and highlighting using java and c++. the problem is that I always get a crash with no exception details. In debugging I found SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)  SIG:9 fault address

[debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb4W6.jpg)

My native function is

```
#include <fpdftext.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_[my package]_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageText(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong pagePtr) {
unsigned short* buffer;
FPDF_TEXTPAGE text_page = FPDFText_LoadPage((FPDF_PAGE) pagePtr);
int len = FPDFText_CountChars(text_page);
FPDFText_GetText(text_page,0,len,buffer);
jstring txt = env->NewString(buffer, len);
FPDFText_ClosePage(text_page);
return txt; }
```

java function in PdfiumCore.java

```
public String getPageText(PdfDocument doc, int pageIndex)
{
    String txt;
    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            txt = nativeGetPageText(openPage(doc,pageIndex));
            return txt;
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error ",e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
    }

}

 public long openPage(PdfDocument doc, int pageIndex) {
    long pagePtr;
    synchronized (lock) {
        pagePtr = nativeLoadPage(doc.mNativeDocPtr, pageIndex);
        doc.mNativePagesPtr.put(pageIndex, pagePtr);

        return pagePtr;
    }

}
```

function call

```
Log.e("Page 0",pdfiumCore.getPageText(pdfDocument,0));
```

The function retrieves the data once then the app crashes. I guess the problem is when the garbage collector tries to delete the buffer pointer which is used in FPDFText_GetText function. but I don't know how to solve it.

any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the pointer after getting the data by using this code in the JNI function

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_[my package]_PdfiumCore_nativeGetPageText(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                              jlong pagePtr) {
jstring txt;
FPDF_TEXTPAGE text_page = FPDFText_LoadPage((FPDF_PAGE) pagePtr);
int len = FPDFText_CountChars(text_page);
unsigned short *buffer = new unsigned short[len];
FPDFText_GetText(text_page, 0, len, buffer);
txt = env->NewString(buffer,len);
delete[](buffer);
FPDFText_ClosePage(text_page);
return txt;}
```